# How to permanently disable OS updates in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm using Windows 7 to download. And Windows update gets in the way making the download slower. How do I disable it permanently? I tried to find the settings in the `msconfig.exe`. But can't find it. I can only disable it on `services.msc`.

Comment: Stopping OS updates let you vulnerable to many broadcasted exploits... It's better to let them enabled but scheduled at a time that not disrupt your work...

Comment: He/She will be vulnerable in general not just to "broadcasted exploits"

Comment: The specious implication of the previous comments is that getting updates makes you secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start | Control Panel | Windows Update | Change Settings, Under Important Updates select "Never check for updates..."

You can still manually check, I would suggest subscribing to the MS notifications and where there are new updates doing a manual check and installing.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is here:

[Windows Update - Enable / Disable Automatic Updates in Windows 7 - Guide](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/515869-windows-update-enable-disable-automatic-updates-windows-7-guide.html)

Answer (score 3):

go to run then type gpedit.msc, then go to administrative templates, find windows components & windows updates. Turn off "configure windows updates"

Answer (score 2):

simplest way is 1. open start menu
2. type "windows update" and hit enter. it will open the window update settings.
3. on the left hand side click on change settings.]
4. choose "never check for update" from the drop down menu.
5. press ok and your settings will be saved.

Answer (score 2):

Go to services and disable the updating service. Usually Windows can't even tell why it can't update, that way.

Comment: The accepted answer is more complete; honestly this answer isn't all that helpful

Comment: It's an alternative. It's not even comparable to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `run` then type gpedit.msc, and from user configuration find the Administrative templates. From there click on windows components and select windows updates. Double click on remove access to all Windows Update features, and make it enable.